# How to append a while function to list?

Tags: python, while-loop, append

How does one append the output of a while function into a list? For example:

```
fib = []

def FIB():
    a,b = 0,1
    while a < 100:
        fib.append(a)
        a, b = b, a + b

print(fib)
```

I am expecting:

```
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

But I receive:

```
[]
```

Comment: You forgot to call the `FIB` function.

Comment: @floydya it's mutable so it doesn't matter, though it's bad practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return fib, so you can print it. You also need to call your function correctly.

```
fib = []

def FIB():
    a,b = 0,1
    while a < 100:
        fib.append(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
    return fib
print(FIB())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fib = []

def FIB(fib):
    a,b = 0,1
    while a < 100:
        fib.append(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
    return fib
print(FIB(fib))
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.